# Separar caracteres de una cadena C#

Tags: c#

Dado el siguiente array
string[] arr= {"A:3","A:5","B:2","B:-1"};

Necesito el siguiente resultado:
string[] arr= {"A:8","B:1"};

Sumar o restar segun sea el caso los que sean de letras iguales.
He intentado lo siguiente pero no lo logro.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
        
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string[] arr= {"A:3","A:5","B:2","B:-1"};
        List<string> list= new List<string>();
        List<string> list2= new List<string>();
        
        for(int i=0; i<arr.Length;i++){
            list.Add(arr[i]);           
        }
             
        foreach(string s in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
            
            for(int i=0; i<s.Length;i++){
                list2.Add(s[i]);            
            }
            
            foreach(var x in list2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(list2);
            }
            
        }
          
    }
}
```

Comment: qué obtienes con este código? Algún error?

Comment: @Alfabravo no hace lo que necesito, nose como continuarlo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yo haría lo siguiente, como el string está definido, crearía una variable de entero por cada letra.
Después, recorrería el arreglo, y verficaría que caracter es el primero, dependiendo de este, definiría a que variable lo voy a agregar sumar. Al final solo mostraría las listas. El código quedaría así:

```
//declaramos array, y variables de suma
            string[] arr = { "A:3", "A:5", "B:2", "B:-1" };
            int sumaA = 0;
            int sumaB = 0;

            //recorremos el array
            foreach(string str in arr)
            {
                //dividimos el segmento mediante el ":" que es quien divide la letra del valor.
               string[] strParts = str.Split(':');
                //si la letra es A, suma a sumaA, si es B, se suma a sumaB
                int.TryParse(strParts[1], out int result);
            int.TryParse(strParts[1], out int result);
            if (strParts[0].Equals("A")){
                
                sumaA += result;
            }
            if (strParts[0].Equals("B"))
            {
                sumaB += result;
            }
            }
            //imprimimos
            Console.WriteLine("Suma de elementos A: "+sumaA.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("Suma de elementos B: "+sumaB.ToString());
```

Comment: Me parece una buena solución aunque se limita a hard codear los elementos: A, B, C, ... Por otra parte el código puede generar errores si la conversión falla. No estaría mal usar un `int.TryParse`.

Comment: el OP no menciona que esto pueda variar, por eso tomé la opción de colocarlo de esa manera, respecto al otro, voy a añadirlo

Answer (score 4):

Puedes recorrer el array y acumular la suma en un Dictionary, esta estructura de datos te permitirá mantener lo que hay delante de los dos puntos ("A","B" etc.) como claves y acumular la suma (lo que hay detrás de los dos puntos) en los valores del Dictionary.

Para devolverlo lo puedes hacer pasando el diccionario a un array con LINQ o simplemente con un bucle, te he puesto los dos ejemplos.

El código sería algo así  :

```
static string[] Acumula(string[] arr)
{
    var acum = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    string[] split;
    foreach (string item in arr)
    {
        split = item.Split(':');
        int.TryParse(split[1], out int result);
        if (acum.ContainsKey(split[0]))
            acum[split[0]] = acum.GetValueOrDefault(split[0], 0) + result;
        else
            acum[split[0]] = result;
    }
    // Si quieres usar LINQ
    return acum.Select(kvp => kvp.Key + ":" + kvp.Value).ToArray();
    // Si no quieres usar LINQ
    //string[] r2 = new string[acum.Count];
    //int i = 0;
    //foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> kvp in acum)
    //    r2[i++] = kvp.Key + ":" + kvp.Value;
    // return r2;
}
```

Para usarlo :

```
string[] arr = { "A:3", "A:5", "B:2", "B:-1" };
string[] res = Acumula(arr);
```

Aqui https://dotnetfiddle.net/CMRAko te he dejado un ejemplo un poco más extenso por si tu array solo lleva un caracter por delante de los dos puntos.

Answer (score 1):

Para darle solución a tu problema te propongo crear tu propio tipo de datos diccionario, el cual tendrá dos propiedades: **propiedad Llave** de tipo **string**, y **propiedad Valor** de tipo **int**. Aclaro que no se usa el tipo de datos **Dictionary** de **.NET**, ya que en este tipo de datos la llave no puede estar repetida, por eso es que creamos nuestro propio diccionario a la medida, ya que en nuestro caso la llave si podrá estar repetida. La clase quedaría así:

```
class Diccionario
{
    public Diccionario(string llave, int valor)
    {
        Llave = llave;
        Valor = valor;
    }

    public string Llave { get; set; }
    public int Valor { get; set; }
}
```

Ahora bien, para realmente lograr lo que pides habrá que hacer el siguiente algoritmo:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Diccionario> lista = new List<Diccionario>();
        string[] arr = { "A:3", "A:5", "B:2", "B:-1" };
        string[] par = new string[2];
        string llave = "";
        int valor = 0;

        foreach (var a in arr)
        {
            par = a.Split(':');
            llave = par[0];
            valor = Convert.ToInt32(par[1]);

            Diccionario d = new Diccionario(llave, valor);

            lista.Add(d);
        }

        var agrupamiento = (from l in lista
                            group l by l.Llave into grupo
                            select new
                            {
                                llave = grupo.Key,
                                Total = grupo.Sum(g => g.Valor),
                                Par = string.Format("{0}:{1}", llave, Total.ToString())
                            }).ToList();

        foreach(var a in agrupamiento)
        {
           Console.WriteLine(a.Par);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Declaramos las siguientes variables:

**lista:** Es una lista del diccionario definido por nosotros.

**arr:** arreglo de tipo **string** que contiene la información a procesar.

**par:** arreglo de tipo **string** que servirá para almacenar la llave y el valor por cada elemento de la lista.

**llave:** variable de tipo **string** que guarda el contenido de la **propiedad Llave** del diccionario definido por nosotros.

**valor:** variable de tipo **int** que guarda el contenido de la **propiedad Valor** del diccionario definido por nosotros.

Posteriormente ejecutaríamos un **foreach** que recorrerá cada elemento de la lista y por cada elemento de la lista se usará la **función Split** para obtener la llave y el valor correspondiente, esta llave y valor obtenidos servirán para crear un diccionario definido por nosotros, a medida que vayamos creando el diccionario lo añadiremos a la lista.

Posteriormente haremos uso de **Linq** para obtener por cada llave la suma de los valores asociados a una llave en común y un campo especial llamado Par que concatena la llave y el total.

Por último imprimimos a través de un **foreach** el resultado final obtenido, es decir imprimiríamos la **propiedad Par** por cada elemento almacenado en la lista obtenida mediante la consulta **Linq** previamente realizada.

Para poder usar **Linq** debemos poner en los **usings**:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: O sea.. hiciste dos pasadas sobre el mismo array, una haciendo el split, y otra sumando todo, cuando se podia hacer en una sola pasada? no entiendo porque hiciste las dos pasadas... :/

Comment: @gbianchi arreglado, gracias :)

Comment: es que.. seguis haciendo dos pasadas.. una para hacer el split.. y otra para hacer la suma... fijate en las otras respuestas.. hacen todo de una... :(

Comment: @gbianchi la primera respuesta es "incorrecta", solo funciona para las llaves "A" y "B", si aparecieran las llaves "C", "D", etc junto a mil llaves mas habria que implementar una solucion macarronica, y la segunda respuesta no veo donde guarda el valor en el diccionario en caso de q no exista la llave, y me parece q tambien hace dos pasadas, en fin de todas las respuestas el usuario marco la "menos buena", en fin todos hacemos dos pasadas

Comment: @Japv si por la segunda respuesta te refieres a la mía (supongo que sí) guarda el valor cuando la clave no existe en el "else acum[split[0]] = result;"

Comment: @adevel ya me di cuenta, yo lo veia como: acum.Add(llave, valor), pero ya veo que se puede hacer como lo tienes hecho: acum[llave] = valor, no obstante y por si acaso jamas hable negativamente de tu respuesta, y respecto a la otra me refiero a ella como "menos buena" no como "mala"

Comment: @adevel tienes mi voto, suerte

Comment: Muchas gracias @Japv